# can't understand why my js file is not found on client console

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, client

this probably is a newbie question, please don't be mean :D

I'm trying to add a js file to an html page, but can't load it properly. It seems to be a path related issue.

in the HTML page I'm linking the file with

```
<script src="../src/utils/mapbox.js"></script>
```

Then on my js file I simply put a console.log to see if the file is loaded properly, but it isn't :/
I tried everything but nothing changes.

screenshot of the debug console
[image: screenshot of the debug console]

screenshot of the source tab of the debuggin tool

[image: screenshot of the source tab of the debuggin tool]

On the second image, I can't see all of my folders I have on VSCode. It is because those file are server side right? If so, how can I solve the issue? :/

this is the folder structure in VSCode

[image: this is the folder structure in VSCode]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your local folder structure? Where is index.html located?

Comment: What web server are you using? What absolute URL is it supposed to share the JS from? What have you done to ensure that?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to share the folder structure on VSCode, please check the edited post

Comment: Where are the css and img folders in the VSCode structure? It doesn't look like those folders map to the web root.

Comment: those are on the public folder, I've setup a public path and they are working fine. Now I think I'm confusing server side with client side links. I need to learn how to link js server side file, on client side. Hope my statement makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `src` attribute needs to be a URL to the JS file.

If you use a relative URL, it needs to be relative to the URL of the HTML document.

This is **not** the same as the path between the EJS template used to generate the HTML and a JS file on the local filesystem.

---

First you need to give the JS file a URL. You haven't shown the source code you've written for your websever, but it seems like a reasonable assumption to say that you have used the Express.js `static` module to make the contents of the `public` directory accessible.

The `src` directory is not inside `public` so it **isn't** accessible. It also appears to be a directory containing your **server-side** source code, so it isn't a suitable place to keep your client-side JS.

**Move the client-side JS files into a directory inside the `public` directory**.

(If you are writing isomorphic JS then you could create a new directory, perhaps called `shared`, and expose it using `static` too).

Once that is done, you can work out the URL to the JS file.

Comment: you're right, I've used express for the public path

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, "../public")
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, "../views")

app.use(express.static(publicPath))

I'll try to move the file inside the public folder, and then link the file again. Thanks for your answer! I need to learn a lot more I think XD

Comment: one more thing, if I move the js file to the public folder, I can't use require in order to load the mapbox npm module... Can you give me a hint on that too? thanks

Comment: @aitenlabs — The penultimate paragraph covers that.

Answer (score 0):

ok I digged into that issue and so basically, I was confusing between client side and server side. I looked at the mapbox api docs and immediately I clicked on the npm quick guide, but this is just for limited cases, when you need to render a map on the server.
All I needed to follow was the web js api of the mapbox service.

So thanks for the comments, I'll try to noob less and study more! :)